# combination of 5 digit numbers

Tags: combinatorics

looking at 5-digit number when digits can be $1,2,...,9$ and with repetition,
$|\Omega|=9^5$

the event of $5$ distinct digits is $9\times 8\times 7\times 6\times 5$? 
and the event 2 digits the same is ${5\choose 2}\times 9\times 1\times 8\times 7\times 6$?

Comment: whats the question?

Comment: @ElliotG if the calculations are right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct for all numbers with repetition and for the number with distinct (not distinguishable) digits.  Your last is correct if you require exactly one pair of matching digits.  $5 \choose 2$ locates the pair of digits, there are $9$ choices for the paired digit the $8,7,6$ for the other three.